# Unable to deploy ear with Netbeans if the package name is changed with Maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, netbeans, glassfish

In order to have a constant JNDI name for remote calls, I want to remove the version from the EAR package name. I do it with the tag < finalName > in the maven-ear-plugin.
It works fine but, when I deploy (run) the package with Netbeans (version 7.1.2), it raises an exception:
*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No archive for deployment*

It seems Netbeans always expects a name like *${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.ear*. How is it possible to change this behaviour?

Edit: It only happens when deploying on remote (Glassfish) servers.

Many thanks!
JM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm working on a Netbeans ear project with the same structure as yours, but when I run or debug the application from Netbeans it deploys the `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.ear` under the `target` folder, the ear generated from the maven-ear-plugin is not used by Netbeans, anyway you can deploy it manually, I've done it successfully. This is a known Netbeans behavior, for example you can refer to this [link](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=213873).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact I try to generate it as ${project.artifactId}.ear, without the version in the file name, to deploy it on a remote server (it doesn't create gfdeploy directory for Glassfish). I can do it manually too, but in this case the debug session doesn't start right at the deployment, I have to attach the debugger afterwards.

Comment: I've investigated some time ago and found that it's a known Netbeans issue, there is no way to debug ears other than with that fool name. I bookmarked the page but I've lost it, maybe it was on Netbeans bugzilla.

Comment: Thank you for this information. That's indeed the behaviour locally.

Comment: You're welcome, please check the answer if you consider it useful.

Comment: I've checked your answer, considering the most important info is in the comments.

Comment: You're right, I've updated the answer to include further information, thanks.

Comment: I have same problem with war

Answer (score 0):

To get a consistent name for your EJBs you first have to get a consistent name for your application. The name of the application can be set in the Application Descriptor File application.xml with the tag `<application-name>YourGreatApp</application-name>`.

If the application name is not set, the EAR file name will be used as application name. With maven you should always set your application name.

The application.xml file resides under META-INF/ in your EAR.

Comment: I've created a deployment file application.xml. I've tried with the tag application-name and even YourGreatApp (where does it come from? Not in the xsd), but it doen't work. It still add version for local deployment and it doesn't deploy remotely.

Comment: Sorry, this was misleading. The Tag name is application-name. So your application.xml should contain a line like this: <application-name>YourGreatApp</application-name>. I changed that in the answer.